# How to use Jailkit Jail Manager in Virtualmin to restrict users

Tags: debian, chroot, jails, webmin

How to use Jailkit Jail Manager in Virtualmin (Webmin 1.892) to restrict users in their homes including virtual website and all services running under user?

I am setting up small website hosting service and I must disable access to everything except user's home.

I dont want to use FTP or FTPS! User's will have full SSH access to their system and they will be able to run for example NodeJS scripts, Teamspeak, etc...

Is it possible? If yes, is it possible in Virtualmin or it needs more and deeper setup.

EDIT: I am using Debian 9

Answer (score 0):

Virtualmin -> select domain/virtual server -> Administration Options -> Edit Owner Limits -> section 'Other restrictions' -> at the bottom 'Chroot jail domain Unix user?'